# SQL CASE statement needs to handle Text

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, case

Apologies if this has been asked before - I've spent a couple of hours searching but not found anything that's helped.

It's quite simple really - I've been asked to create a query which includes a field that when it was set up (not by me) was created as a VARCHAR instead of an INT.

I need to do some calculations on this field, however some users have been entering text into it, so the calculations fail as it can't convert the data to an INT.

Is there anything I can add to a CASE statement to handle where there's text?

I was thinking something like the below, but don't know what the actual code is:

```
CASE
    WHEN [Field1] IS TEXT THEN 1 ;
    ELSE [Field2] as [Chose name]
END
```

Edit: Note that this is in MS SQL Server.
Thanks.

Comment: Btw: that's a CASE **expression** not a statement.

Comment: Thanks for filling forums with useless info.

Comment: This isn't a forum, @TomCamish, nor is it useless info. A `CASE` expression and a `Case` (`Switch`) statement are completely different. `Case` statements do **not** exist in T-SQL; to replicate their logic you would have to use `IF...ELSE` statements.

Comment: [`SQL_Variant_Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sql-variant-property-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) can be used to check the data type of a column, e.g. `select SQL_Variant_Property( '42', 'basetype' ) as StringType, SQL_Variant_Property( 42, 'basetype' ) as NumericType;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `try_convert()` and `isnull()` for this:

```
isnull(try_convert(int, field), 1)
```

`try_convert()` attempts you cast `field` to an `int`. When that fails, `null` is returned; you can trap that with `isnull()` and turn the result to `1` instead.

Note that this only works as long as `field` is not `null` (otherwise, you would get `1` as a result).

Comment: Thank you for your assistance - this has worked perfectly. Much appreciated. Luckily, I need the query to return a 1 if it's already NULL.

Answer (score 0):

**In SQL Server**

```
Declare @Salary varchar(100);                                
Set @Salary = 50000;                                       
Select Case when ISNUMERIC(@Salary) = 1 then 1 
            else 0 end as [Check]
```

May be this will be Helpful.